# Flutter run error : path_provider_linux.dart Constant expression expected

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages, flutter-run

When I try to run the Flutter project on the IOS simulator I am facing the following issue :

`Error (Xcode): ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/path_provider_linux-2.1.11/lib/src/path_provider_linux.dart:24:58: Error: Constant expression expected.`

This might have caused by the new packages that I have added to my project.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by:

1. go to the package cache folder of Flutter, which was in '/Users//.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev'
2. Delete the path_provider_linux folder entirly
3. Go to root of your project and run `flutter pub get`
4. Run the project

However I think It can be fixed by the following steps as well:

1. `flutter pub cache clean`
2. Go to root of your project and run `flutter pub get`
3. Run the project